# Adding id's for Bootstraptable react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to add an id for the Bootstraptable tag of react-bootstrap-table module. I saw the props. there is a tablebodyclass prop in which we can set the class name. But i want the table to be unique. How shall i introduce Id for the table?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't think it's required.

Answer (score 0):

Give add to the top of table

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <BootStrapTable id="abc"> ... </BootStrapTable> . This does not work

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles into this question with **"react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3"**

```
<BootstrapTable id="someID" ... />
```

This works charm

Inspect result :

```
<table id="someID" class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><thead> ... </thead><table>
```